# Restrict access for website to Front Door only without custom domain - is it possible?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door

I would like your feedback and opinion about using { FrontDoor + Appservices + Authentication + restrict access to FD only }

I do confirm I can set up all of this thanks to all contribution/ forums / blog found on the net. I can use my custom domain which request AD authentication and I am correctly redirect to my appservices (in browser: I see my custom domain name and never see any *.azurefdnet or *azurewebsites.net as expected).

The only problem is that I needed to use a **custom domain** to make it works. For production purpose it is acceptable to have a custom domain but for dev or test I wonder if we can do it without custom domain by simply keeping original address like *.azurefd.net and *.azurewebsites.net

I struggle to make it works **without custom domain**. I keep getting “too many redirection” message or ‘403 sites blocked’.
Does anyone success to do it ? My general configuration looks like
[image]

My backend is linked with my appservices

[image]

Details of my backend is:

[image]

I think my problem is with *BackendHostHeader* but not sure. When i used custom domain for my production it works. But remind i do not want to use custom domain for dev and test.

My route looks like

[image]

And finally my appservices is secure to allow frontdoor only

[image]

When my user goes to stackoverflo.azurefd.net they get AD authentication which is good but just after i get redirection to xxx.azurewebsites.net with 403 forbidden (which looks normal because of restriction to FD only).

I tried to change the *backend host header* by replacing by FD value but in this case i get a error with loop redirection.

Is it a feasible scenario without custom domain ?
Regards

PS: i configured Azure ADApp to allow reply url to my FD like stackoverflo.azurefd.net/.auth/login/aad/callback

Answer (score 0):

- *Yes, you can **Restrict** the access to website without using **Custom Domain**.*
- *Goto the **Application** you want to restrict the access in **Azure Portal** and select the Networking from left Pane, now click on **Access Restrictions**.*

[image]

[image]

[image]

- *For complete information you can go through this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions).*

Comment: Hi SaiSakethGuduru-MT
Thanks for our answser. I already configured a network restrictions as you suggested (see my attached screenshot in original post). I follow documentation recommendation and set as 'service-tag' to 'frontDoor backend'. I do confirm that when i try to reach the appservice i get a 403 forbidden page as expected because of network restriction. So it works like a charm.

My problem is with FrontDoor. When i reach FD page, i am redirect to Auth page then after that i get the 403 forbidden. 

Any idea ?